# What is the best method to format data that is a list of categories into an adjacency matrix?

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, data-processing

I have data that I plan to feed into an sklearn model.  A few of the columns are lists of categories (its movie data, so for example one column is `{genres: [comedy, horror]}`).

What can I do to process these columns, so that what's fed into the model is an adjacency matrix where the row then has some of the data like the following?

```
{comedy: 1, action: 0, horror: 1, documentary: 0}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The preprocessor you're looking for is [`LabelBinarizer`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.LabelBinarizer.html)

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelBinarizer

data = [{'genres': ['comedy', 'horror']}, {'genres': ['action', 'documentary']}]
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# explode the list to separate rows
X = pd.concat([
        pd.DataFrame(v, index=np.repeat(k,len(v)), columns=['genre']) 
            for k,v in df.genres.to_dict().items()])

lb = LabelBinarizer()
# make the binary fields
dd = pd.DataFrame(lb.fit_transform(X), index=df_exploded.index, columns=lb.classes_)
dd.groupby(dd.index).max()
```

Gives

```
   action  comedy  documentary  horror
0       0       1            0       1
1       1       0            1       0
```

Comment: Thank you, the middle step with panda is what I was missing. That helps a bunch, I'll accept your answer as soon as I implement it.